# Get the index of a node's parent, passing its index, in a balanced tree

Tags: c#, math, logic, nodes, treenode

### Example:

I have the following example, that illustrate a championship schedule:

```
1 2  3 4  5 6  7 8
 |    |    |    |
 9   10    11  12
   |         |    
  13         14 
        |
       15
```

#### Rules:

*The numbers represent the values of the nodes(matched). The value start from top to root, as the root is the final match of a championship.*

*The tree will be **always balanced**, and can have N top positions where N = {2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256...}*

### Problem:

I need to find a math function that will return the value of the node parent, passing its value. And this math function must be possible to be represented in C#.

```
GetNodeParent(9); // must return 13
GetNodeParent(10); // must return 13
GetNodeParent(4); // must return 10
GetNodeParent(15); // must return null
```

How should be the function?

Comment: `GetNodeParent(Int32 nodeIndex)` method does not have enough information to complete the task. In addition to the number of the node it needs to know either the total number of nodes, or the number of levels (which is equivalent, really).

Comment: Are you passing the index, or the value? Because if you only pass the value you need to pass the whole array too. If you're passing the value (which I think you are, according to your examples), it's a really really bad naming you did there.

Comment: I need to pass the index. My index is not 0 based, and the root is the last index.

Comment: Oh I see, that's because you did your tree top down. Normally you start with the root at index 0, my bad.

Comment: In my real world situation, the tree represent a championship schedule matches, the number 15 will be the last fight match. Thats why it is top down

Comment: what do you hold your data in? array? list?

Comment: The data is hold in a list

Comment: With least common multiple your find how many levels exist in tree!

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the easiest way to handle this would be to store your tree the other way around. Normally a balanced tree can be represented in an array with the root at the first position and the leafs taking the last `n/2` positions, looking like this :

```
         1
         |
   2            3 
   |            |  
 4   5       6      7  
 |    |      |      |
8 9 10 11  12 13 14 15
```

which will look like this in memory :

```
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15
```

Now an interesting property of this construction, is that the parent is *always* at `Math.Floor(index/2)` (so the children are at `n*2` and `n*2+1`)

For example, the parent of `13` is `13/2 = 6.5 =floored= 6`. It really simplifies the operations.

As said previously, all the leaf nodes are in the last n/2 positions. This is an other interesting fature; if you're looking for the first round matches, simply chop your array and take the `Math.Ceiling(n/2)` last items :

1|2|3|4|5|6|7|**8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15**

For the second round, remove the previous round and chop again at `Math.Ceiling(n/2)` :

1|2|3|**4|5|6|7|**

---

So knowing this, `GetParent` can look like the following :

```
public static int? GetParent(int childIndex)
{
    int parentIndex = (int) Math.Floor((double)childIndex/2);
    return parentIndex == 0 ? (int?)null : parentIndex;
}
```

or directly `return (int)Math.Floor((double)index/2);` if you don't need the null values.

This can be verified with this simple unit test made from your example values' position:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    Assert.AreEqual(2, Stuff.GetParent(4));
    Assert.AreEqual(2, Stuff.GetParent(5));
    Assert.AreEqual(6, Stuff.GetParent(13));
    Assert.AreEqual(null, Stuff.GetParent(1));
}
```

And also don't forget to work with indexes and not values, you can't directly apply the 9 and get 13 from your example, it's 4 and 2 now because that's their index in the tree with the root at the first position, which is constructed like. The example you provided would be constructed like that :

```
15|13|14|9|10|11|12|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8
```

You can use `IndexOf` if you need to work by values. Since you're 1-based instead of 0-based, you'll also need to add 1 to every index. That would look like this :

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        List<int> values = new List<int>{15, 13, 14, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

        Assert.AreEqual(values.IndexOf(13) + 1, Stuff.GetParent(values.IndexOf(9) + 1));
        Assert.AreEqual(values.IndexOf(13) + 1, Stuff.GetParent(values.IndexOf(10) + 1));
        Assert.AreEqual(values.IndexOf(10) + 1, Stuff.GetParent(values.IndexOf(4) + 1));
        Assert.AreEqual(null, Stuff.GetParent(values.IndexOf(15)));
    }
```

Comment: This is really close to what i want but is there a way to get the same result but with the tree root as the last number? Because in my real world situation, the tree represent a championship. And the root is the last thing that will happens, its the final match. I am not able to modify its order now.

Comment: It is highly recommended to build your tree in the correct format. You would not be able to rebalance it later if it's upside down. I detailed the way to work with your previous values with the tree constructed with the root as the first element.

Comment: I will try to fild a way to the root be the 1 value. I think the word index that I used on my question is confusing, since it is not an index of array or list or w/e. It is just the value. I dont have a real tree structure where nodes references their parents. The tree is just an illustration of my championship schedule.

Comment: Hm, then the easiest way to handle that would really think the game #1 as the final. However, since all games will be distinct, you can use the 'IndexOf' part described last to get the real array index.. But making the mental conversion each time can be cumbersome. I've also included detailed a way to get the games by tiers, if that can help somehow...

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Build a new tree that is the reverse, so you can use binary trees.

---

Option 2:

Call wil the `list_name.Count()`, I've used 15 for your case

```
GetNodeParent(9,15); // return 13
GetNodeParent(10,15);// return 13
GetNodeParent(4,15); // return 10
```

This works, but you'll have to check for the end cases (15 in your case):

```
int GetNodeParent(int aNodeValue, int aListSize) {
    aNodeValue.Dump("Look for the parent of");
    var depth = (int)(Math.Log(aListSize,2) ); // this rounds down
    var level = Math.Pow(2,depth);
    while (aNodeValue > level) {
        depth--;
        level += Math.Pow(2,depth);
    }
    var target = level+1;   // this will be our accumulator
    var search = level;     // for our "binary search"
    var search_width = Math.Pow(2,depth).Dump("width");
    // This runs a "binary search", adding 1 to our result
    // if we are on the right side.
    while (search_width!=0){
       if (aNodeValue > level)
            target++;
        search -= search_width / 2;
        search_width /=2;
    }       

    return (int)target;
}
```

as an after thought, add an `if (aNodeValue == list_name.Count())` before you call the method, for the `null`, or change the signature to `int?` and do the check in the method so it'll return null

Comment: Saddly, I am not able to build a new reverse tree in my real world situation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this simple formula?

```
GetNodeParent(k) = (k + 1) div 2 + N
(if >=2N then null)
```

where **div** is integer division (7 div 2 = 3)